# How to display most used file extensions (pdf, doc, docx, xls, ...) into a browser using PHP?

Tags: php, file

Currently developping a mobile webmail for my school, I am encountering the iPhone problem : iPhone users are enable to download files, so I would like to allow them, at least, to consult their files with the common extensions : doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf, ppt, pptx, XML, open office files, an so on.

Does something exist to do that using PHP or HTML/Javascript ?

Comment: You're probably talking about setting correct headers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: It seems to work for pdf files since most of browser are able to open pdf files, but how to be sure a mobile browser will be able to open for example a docx file correctly ?

Comment: Probably not. But there's not much you can do about it. You could try to find libraries which allow you to make an HTML or image preview of the document, similar to what Google does. Or if you know that all clients can display pdf files, I'd try to convert them to pdf, that's probably easier.

Comment: Ahhh... Now I see I misread your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use google doc's viewer: http://docs.google.com/viewer

This will allow you to display all of these formats directly in the browser.

Basically you just have to do this to display a document:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?=urlencode($document_url)?>&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

(Note that google docs must have access to these documents, which may or may not make this solution unsuitable.)

Comment: Okay, this is truly awesome. At least for non-confidental documents.

Comment: In fact it is awesome, but how can I use it for attachments, as there doesn't exist any direct link to access them ? (sorry, I forgot to mention that I wanted to make attachments displayable).

Comment: you will have to make them available at some url

Comment: I guess so, but how can I do that ? I tried to echo them with a force-download header, but Google doesn't seem to accept that :/

Comment: last time I tried, the viewer was only taking the file suffix into account, not the content-type (adding `&format=.doc` at the end of the URL, without urlencoding the `.`, did the trick ;-) )

Comment: @arnaud576875 Hi, I'm having the same issue and I found this answer to be the best there is, but what I'm concern about security of my files inside my App.